# linux mount issue with fstab

Tags: linux, mount

I'm trying to create a ramdisk inside a VM. I think I have the ability to use tmpfs, because it is Ubuntu 10.04 which comes with kernel > 2.6. I added this to `/etc/fstab`:

```
none /mnt/test tmpfs defaults,user,size=1G,mode=0777 0 0
```

Then why I try to `mount /mnt/test`, I get:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on none,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       (for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might
       need a /sbin/mount.<type> helper program)
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

What to do ?

Comment: Does `mount tmpfs /mnt -t tmpfs -o size=1G` work?

Comment: yes, solved it, thanks. But why ? (the -o option isn't necessary, but the rest is).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the Lucid man page doesn't properly tell you the first field for tmpfs.

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man5/fstab.5.html

Replace 'none' with 'tmpfs'.